# How to select programs by multi tags

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE programs (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE program_tag (
    program_id INT NOT NULL,
    tag_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (program_id, tag_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_program FOREIGN KEY(program_id) REFERENCES programs(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tag FOREIGN KEY(tag_id) REFERENCES tags(id)
);
```

A program can have multiple tags. I want to select program with tags. Tags must exactly match the program. The query I'm using is this:

```
SELECT * FROM programs p
WHERE p.id IN (SELECT program_id FROM program_tag pt JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.id WHERE t.name = 'tag1')
AND p.id IN (SELECT program_id FROM program_tag pt JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.id WHERE t.name = 'tag2')
```

This query does exactly what I want. but I don't know if it's the best way to do it.

- If the program has 3 tags instead of 2, I will have to change the query. How can I make this query dynamic?
- Does this query create a performance problem?

Answer (score -2):

```
/*Create Procedure nameProcedure*/
declare @tags varchar(max) = ''
/*Create Format @tag = 'tag1','tag2','tag3'*/
set @tag = 'tag1','tag2','tag3';
/*drop registers new table or temporal table*/
INSERT INTO newTable
SELECT * FROM programs p
WHERE p.id IN (SELECT program_id FROM program_tag pt JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.id WHERE t.name IN (@tags))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).